# Need help with simple NHibernate mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Need help with a simple NHibernate relationship...

Tables/Classes

```
Request
-------
RequestId
Title
…


Keywords
-------
RequestID (key)
Keyword (key)
```

Request mapping file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="CR.Model" assembly="CR">
 <class name="CR.Model.Request, CR table="[dbo].[Request]" lazy="true">
  <id name="Id" column="[RequestID]">
    <generator class="native" />
  </id>
  <property name="RequestorID" column="[RequestorID]" />
  <property name="RequestorOther" column="[RequestorOther]" />
  …

  Keyword??
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

How do I simply map multiple keywords to a request? I don't need another mapping file for the keyword class, do I?
It's be great if I could not only get the associated keywords, but add them too...

Comment: If you're new to NHibernate try looking at Fluent NHibernate, it makes mapping SO much easier! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a set (or some other kind of collection mapping, but I think a set is the best-fit).

[check this](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/13/nhibernate-mapping-ltsetgt.aspx)

Comment: I SWEAR I've searched Ayende's blog high and low and never saw that post. Guh. Great find. Thanks a ton! I think I'll be able to figure it out...

Comment: @mplarsen you could have checked the docs too... http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections